# how to run sql query on pyspark using python?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am very new in pyspark.i didn't code in pyspark so I need help to run sql query on pyspark using python.

can you please tell me how to create dataframe and then view and run sql query on top of it?
what are the modules required to run the query?
Can you please help me how to run?

The data is coming from file TERR.txt

sql query:

```
select a.id as nmitory_id, a.dscrptn as nmitory_desc,  a.nm as terr_nm, a.pstn_type, a.parnt_terr as parnt_nm_id, b.nm as parnt_terr_nm, a.start_dt, a.type, 
CASE
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('105-30',
                                                         '105-31',
                                                         '105-32',
                                                         '105-41',
                                                         '105-42',
                                                         '105-43',
                                                         '200-CD',
                                                         '200-CG',
                                                         '200-CO',
                                                         '200-CP',
                                                         '200-CR',
                                                         '200-DG'
                                                         )
                       THEN
                           'JBI'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('100-SC',
                                                         '105-05',
                                                         '105-06',
                                                         '105-07',
                                                         '105-08',
                                                         '105-13',
                                                         '105-71',
                                                         '105-72',
                                                         '105-73'
                                                         )
                       THEN
                           'JP'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('103-16')
                       THEN
                           'JT'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('105-51',
                                                         '200-HA',
                                                         '200-HF',
                                                         '200-HT',
                                                         '105-HT')
                       THEN
                           'JSA'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('105-61',
                                                         '200-PR')
                       THEN
                           'PR'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 3) IN ('302')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - MEM'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 3) IN ('301')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - MSL'
                       ELSE
                           'Unspecified'
                   END
                       AS DEPARTMENT,
                          CASE
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('105-06',
                                                         '105-07',
                                                         '105-08'
                                                         )
                                     THEN
                                                            'CVM MSL'
                      WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('100-SC',
                                                         '105-13'
                                                         )
                                     THEN
                                                            'CVM CSS'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('105-41',
                                                         '200-CD'
                                                         )
                                     THEN
                                                            'Derm MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('105-42',
                                                         '200-CG'
                                                         )
                                     THEN
                                                            'Gastro MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('105-31')
                                     THEN
                                                            'Heme Onc MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('200-DG')
                                     THEN
                                                            'Imm MD'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('103-16')
                                     THEN
                                                            'ID MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('200-CP')
                                     THEN
                                                            'Imm Ops'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('105-05',
                                                         '105-71',
                                                         '105-72',
                                                         '105-73'
                                                         )
                                     THEN
                                                            'Neuro MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('105-30',
                                                         '200-CO'
                                                         )
                                     THEN
                                                            'Onc MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('105-61',
                                                         '200-PR'
                                                         )
                                     THEN
                                                            'Puerto Rico MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('105-43',
                                                         '200-CR'
                                                         )
                                     THEN
                                                            'Rheum MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('105-51',
                                                         '200-HF'
                                                         )
                                     THEN
                                                            'RWVE Field'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('105-32')
                                     THEN
                                                            'Solid Tumor MSL'
                      WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('200-HT',
                                                                                         '105-HT')
                                     THEN
                                                            'RWVE Pop Health'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('301-PC')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - PC MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('301-VR')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - VR/ONC MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('301-SO')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - Hematology (Myeloid) MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('301-ON')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - Hematology (Lymphoid) MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('301-IP')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - CNS MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('301-RD')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - Rheum MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('301-IB')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - Gastro MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('301-DE')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - Derm MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('301-SE')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - Biologics MSL'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('302-PC')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - PC MEM'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('302-VR')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - VR/ONC MEM'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('302-SO')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - Hematology (Myeloid) MEM'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('302-ON')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - Hematology (Lymphoid) MEM'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('302-IP')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - CNS MEM'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('302-RD')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - Rheum MEM'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('302-IB')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - Gastro MEM'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('302-DE')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - Derm MEM'
                       WHEN substr (a.nm, 1, 6) IN ('302-SE')
                       THEN
                           'Canada - Biologics MEM'
                       ELSE
                           'Unspecified'
                   END
                       AS FRANCHISE
from outbound.terr a left outer join outbound.terr b on a.parnt_terr = b.id
```

Answer (score 12):

You should create a temp view and query on it.

For example:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("sample").getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.load("TERR.txt")

df.createTempView("example")
df2 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM example")
```

Comment: should i need to create dataframe first? if yes then can you please guide me?

Comment: @abhishek I've updated my answer. If there is any problem please inform me.

Comment: can you please write down whole code with importing all modules?

Comment: @abhishek I've created spark session in my answer.

Comment: i have to create dataframe from TERR.txt file then create View and top of it run sql query.

Comment: why do we need to create a view to use sql? A link to the official doc or something would be great for new users.

Answer (score 1):

Save your query to a variable like a string, and assuming you know what a `SparkSession` object is, you can use `SparkSession.sql` to fire the query on the table:

```
df.createTempView('TABLE_X')
query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_X"

df = spark.sql(query)
```

To read a csv into Spark:

```
def read_csv_spark(spark, file_path):
    df = (
        spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .options(header="true", inferSchema="true")
            .load(file_path)
    )
    return df

df = read_csv_spark(spark, "/path/to/file.csv")
```

Comment: should i need to create dataframe first? if yes then can you please guide me?

Comment: what is TABLE_X?

Comment: @abhishek It's a temporary name as an SQL table that we give to the dataframe

Comment: can you please write down the whole code with all modules?

Comment: @abhishek Sure, if you think StackOverflow is a code-writing service.

Comment: will you be write down please?